# Apache Spark RDD Workflow

Tags: apache-spark, apache-camel

I'm trying to use Spark's MLib on a huge dataset that we currently have persisted in a time series database. Let's say if we have data A, B, C, D and E in our time series database, I would want to load A, B, C and do some transformation first and then pass the transformed data into Spark MLib.

I have a couple of questions in this regard. Is there any standard workflow that I should consider? I mean the loading, transforming of data still seems to be a question to me. This is not something specific to Spark. I would like to know if there is any benefit of using frameworks like Apache Camel for doing the ETL and then feed the results to Spark?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loading and transforming data is certainly not something specific to spark, but it is something that it is very good at.  You get a lot of nice features for free, such as fault tolerance, laziness, fast batch processing, and a consistent DSL for everything.

Do you need to specifically cache at stages?

Want to combine data from SQL, S3, Kafka, and Twitter without maintaining 20 different ETL scripts?

Spark can do all that.

There are some restrictions too; Spark needs to be able to build a lineage graph from the data set and its specified transformations, and any ops that aren't idempotent (Like HTTP Requests) kind of break that.

Extremely general summary without knowing more:

1. If you "own" all sources of data (that is they reside in a DB or something), combine all your ETL and mllib programs.  Then you don't have to play hot potato with gigs and gigs of data.
2. If you need to rely on some sources of external data, write some code to grab it and make it owned.